Gaussian curve fit, OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
I am trying to fit a (double) Gaussian function to a two-dimensional data set with scipy.optimize curve_fit. Here is the code
df = np.loadtxt(fname=r"...mydat.dat")

X = np.asarray( np.linspace(0, 448, 449) )
Y = np.asarray( np.linspace(0, 448, 449) )

xdata = (np.asarray( np.meshgrid(X, Y) ) ).reshape(2, 201601) # reformatting data for curve_fit

def Gauss(x, A, B, C, D):
 z = A * e **( ( x[0] - 224 )**2 + ( x[1] - 224 )**2 )/2*B + C * e**( ( x[0] - 224)**2 + ( x[1] - 224) **2 )/2D
 return z

parameters, covariance = curve_fit(Cauchy, xdata, Z)

This leads to : OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
The mean of the data should be at the coordinates (224,224). The obvious problem is that the number e**(224**2) must now be stored at some point - which can't be done with double precision floats. I have tried the decimalfp package, but this did not resolve it. I expect the numbers here are just too large. Currently I have resolved this problem by switching to a Cauchy distribution. Still, this problem could in principle be solved easily by reducing the value of the coordinates, so its bothering me. Any advice?

Take logarithms? Rescale x by sigma?
